# Redirect console.log output to file

Tags: node.js, file, console.log

This should be a trivial question but I don't seem to get my mind around it. Is there any simple way to just redirect all my `console.log` output to a file? `console.log` formats the objects provided in a way that is nice and interacts properly with objects that are not trivial JSONable objects.

For example, if I do

```
var myerr = new Error('There has been an error');
console.log(myerr);
```

I get

```
[Error: There has been an error.]
```

While if I just do

```
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(myerr));
```

I get

```
{}
```

And if I do

```
process.stdout.write(myerr.toString());
```

I get

```
Error: There has been an error
```

So if I override my `console.log` with a function that loops on its arguments with any of the tricks above and redirects the output to a file the log will not be exactly the same.

So I wonder: what does `console.log` do to process the objects it is provided with before outputting them to the console? It just calls `.toString()` on every object, wraps things with `[]` and sends everything to `process.stdout.write`? Or does it do some other kind of preprocessing?

Answer (score 9):

I think the simple way is to use linux I/O redirection.
Just run your application in this way:

```
node app.js > log.txt
```

Then all output messages from your app will be redirected to log.txt

Answer (score 3):

The code of [Console](http://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js) reads:

```
Console.prototype.log = function() {
  this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

You can simply do

```
const util = require('util');
process.stdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
```

Comment: Here is the complete code of node/console.js on [github][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js

Answer (score 0):

Another great way to do this with more granular control on your logs is using winston. See the file transport here: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using ES6 proxies. Most credit goes to https://2ality.com/2015/10/intercepting-method-calls.html

```js
function traceMethodCalls(obj)
{
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, methodName, receiver) {
            // get origin method
            const originMethod = target[methodName];

            return function(...args) {
                // write to file here

                // call origin method
                return originMethod.apply(this, args);
            };
        }
    });
}

console = traceMethodCalls(console);

console.log("log");
console.warn("warn");
console.error("error");
```